# Website not scaling properly on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, web, viewport

I am using the following meta tag on a [website](http://smalltheme.esy.es)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, height=device-height">
```

I want it to occupy 100% of the height.It works like a charm on desktop but while testing it on a mobile it does not stretch to vertically. Could you please help me out.

Comment: Well what's wrong with it?

Comment: Set the `<html>` height to `100%`

Comment: And you'll probably want to remove the inline height and width for the images, and use `max-width:100%; height:auto` on them instead.

Comment: @user3274745 - Nevermind, I completely misread the issue. NickR I believe is right, or at least it's likely.  If you want an element (any element) to take 100% of the viewport height, the <html> tag has to be height:100%; too.

Comment: Thanks michael but it is not scalling properly now

Comment: @user3274745 Set the `<a>` tag and `<img>` tag to height 100% in the `CSS`

Comment: Alright let me try it out

Comment: thanks a lot @NickR i had forgotten to make the a tags to make their height 100%. Thanks

Comment: I believe that the separators in your `meta` tag should be `;`, not `,`.

Comment: No it doesn't make much a difference @AndyM

Comment: Well the height was sorted out but @NickR the width is now not scaling